# I would like to use messages stored in DB

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I would like to use messages stored in DB instead of properties file.

I have an implementation class of `StandardMessageResolver` , inside this class `mongoOperation` is not autowired.
I tried to autowire `applicationContext` but it was not autowired....
I feel like this process run before creating application context or scope setting is something wrong.

Do you have any good idea to solve this problem?

```
public class MyMessageResolver extends StandardMessageResolver implements MessageSource{

private MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
protected MongoOperations mongoOperation;
}
```

refered article:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/22141-i18n-and-the-database

UPDATE: my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("demo.mongo.model")
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
@Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
private String profileActive;

@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String proAppName;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
private String mongoHost;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
private String mongoPort;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
private String mongoDB;

private String mongoHost2;

@Override
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext()
        throws ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.mongoMappingContext();
}

@Override
@Bean
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("start " + profileActive + "environment, " + proAppName + "started");
    System.out.println("mongo host: "+ mongoHost);
    System.out.println("mongo db: "+ mongoDB);
    return new MongoClient(mongoHost + ":" + mongoPort);
}

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mongoDB;
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(){
    try {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), this.getDatabaseName());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your  configuration? Do you get an error during initialization?

Comment: I have prepared a class extends AbstractMongoConfiguration and it is initiated when spring  boot starts.For normal web application it works but try to use this bean in AbstractMongoConfiguration not working.
The error is null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to autowire a `MongoOperations` in your `MyMessageResolver` you'll need both of them to be Spring beans. In order to achieve this just declare both of them in your ApplicationContext (using XML, JavaConfig or component scanning with annotations)

Comment: Thank you.I have my definition like this, it works for the simple web application implements using controller....

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what's your spring configuration would be, but in order to autowire any bean into class, that class should be also part of bean hierarchy.

In other words, `MyMessageResolver` should be decorated with any of below annotation.

```
1) @Controller
2) @Service
3) @Component
4) @Repository
```

Reference: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/

Comment: Thanks I tried but not working in MyMessageResolver....
In side  extension of org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.StandardMessageResolver any annotation provided spring is not working.
If I add ApplicationContext as constructor argument in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, it works......
>templateEngine.setMessageResolver((IMessageResolver) new MyMessageResolver(context));

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that enabling @annotations provided by spring in my code, It is necessary to instantiated by ApplicationContext.getBean.Just create class by new class is not working......

```
//templateEngine.setMessageResolver((IMessageResolver) new MyMessageResolver(context));
templateEngine.setMessageResolver((IMessageResolver) context.getBean(MyMessageResolver.class));
```